# Creating a composite-type descriptor for Postgres composie-types

Tags: postgresql

I have some composite types from Postgresql that I want to obtain their property before fetching them to my application. I want to create a descriptor to obtain the meta-data of the composite type.
Here is the query:

```sql
CREATE TYPE address AS
(county varchar(2), zip varchar(2));
```

How do I create a program to fetch the metadata about the type, and the column(s) of the type using Postgresql API functions.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "descriptor". If you are developing something, please tag the programming language you are using.

Comment: Read the section titled "[pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/catalog-pg-type.html)" under "[System Catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/catalogs.html)" in the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/index.html). At a minimum, you'll need to reference the `pg_type`, `pg_class`, and `pg_attribute` system catalogs.